# How to extract single line in block of HTML code

Tags: php, html, regex

I have contents as:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://website/fox/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="The Fox" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://images.Fox.com/2014/09/foxandforset.gif?w=209" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Fox goes to forest" />
```

My requirement here is to extract/get one line, i.e. `meta property=og:image..` so result should contain:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://images.Fox.com/2014/09/foxandforset.gif?w=209" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracting a "line" of HTML, or using regular expressions to parse HTML in general, is brittle. More robust would be to use an HTML parser such as the support provided by the [DOM extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

#### Example:

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://website/fox/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="The Fox" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://images.Fox.com/2014/09/foxandforset.gif?w=209" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Fox goes to forest" />
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nodes = $xpath->query('//meta[@property="og:image"]');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo $dom->saveHTML($node);
}
```

#### Output:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://images.Fox.com/2014/09/foxandforset.gif?w=209">
```

Comment: Hi @Paul, Tried with your code but no result .. Is Dom extension is enabled by default ? I am using Linux .

Answer (score 1):

```
^<meta property="og:image".*$
```

Try this.Set flags `m` and `g`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/48

Comment: I tried using your regular expression but no result..             $pattern = '/^<meta property="og:image".*$/gm';

preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

Comment: @user3823995 it should .you can see in demo.

Comment: Hi @vks, Checked demo . its working there.. but I am trying this with PHP and its not working.